# Is there any way in typescript to use objects as keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have tow classes:

```
class A {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(name: string, age: number) { 
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
  }
}

class B extends A {

}
```

Also i have an object where i want to use instances of these classes as keys:

```
const storage: Storage = {};
```

So it will look like this:

```
const a = new A('Neo', 25);
const b = new A('Smith', 31);
storage[a] = 'What are you trying to tell me? That I can dodge bullets?';
storage[b] = 'Never send a human to do a machine's job.'
```

And then i want to differ value by keys, like:

```
const keys = Object.keys(storage);
keys.forEach(key => {
  if (key instanceof A) {
    console.log('This is Neo');
  } else if (key instanceof B) {
    console.log('This is Smith');
  }
})
```

How should looks like `Storage` interface, because in typescript

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'

Comment: This use case looks like you'd be fine with just an array of pairs, like `const storage: Array<[A, string]>`, and `storage.push([a, 'What are...']);`.  Why do you need to index into `storage` by an object?  Can you show a use case where it matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way in typescript to use objects as keys?

No, not with object literals.

However, you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead:

> The `Map` object holds key-value pairs. *Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.*

Comment: How i can specify interface for `Map` that is should use as keys only instances of `A` and `B` class?

Comment: You could subclass `Map` with your own implementation.

Comment: [TypeScript’s `Map` takes two type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21), so you can specify the types of your keys and values: `new Map<K, V>()`

Comment: Could you expand on "not with object literals" for the benefit of those who aren't familiar with the potential pitfalls of using `Map`?  That is, since `Map` uses object identity for key equality, if you put a value into the map using an object as a key, you can only retrieve it using the *same object*... which can bite you if you ever deserialize or clone objects in your code.

Comment: @jcalz Not exactly sure what you mean. If you want to know more about [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/map), it is usually best to read the post on MDN and the linked specifications.